# Custom SharePoint timer job is not visible in the central admin

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

A custom SharePoint timer job is not visible in the central admin job definition section.

I have:

1. Activated feature in the application,
2. Restarted the SharePoint timer services,
3. Restarted IIS using Powershell,
4. Tried activating feature using PowerShell using feature id.

Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application service is running in app server and web front end.

What could be the problem? I checked  ULS logs, there is no exception showing.

Comment: try open CA as administrator and/or with systemaccount

Comment: I am using admin accounts only, i am able to activate feature but its seen nowhere in job definition.

Comment: can you find your timerjob with powershell? Get-SPTimerJob | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "YourTJName*"}

Comment: Is your feature copied to the Features folder on your server (C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\YOUR_FEATURE_NAME)?

Comment: yes, Gwny i am able to see that in the 15 hive directory.

Comment: Is your feature web application level

Comment: Yes, Niranjan its scope is Web Application.

Answer (score 1):

1. If there is any alternate mapping for your site, check the exact Web Application URL in Central Administration.
2. Deploy the timer job for the same URL.
3. Restart the SharePoint Timer Service in Services.
4. Go to Site Collection Features or Site Features and activate the timer job feature.

Then you should see the timer job in the Central Administration.