# SharePoint TimerJob

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, timer-jobs

I have deployed successfully a wsp, but when I go to Central Administration -> Monitoring -> Check Job Status it's missing.

Any ideas what could be the reason for that?

Comment: Have you restarted the SPTimerV4 service after the timer job's deployment?

Comment: Also, although confirmed to be answered, see the more or less same question https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148822/custom-sharepoint-timer-job-is-not-visible-in-the-central-admin

Comment: Ensure the Timer Job Feature exist and enabled in Web Application in CA. If exist, enable and disable the feature. If still not working perhaps check solution then redeploy. Don't forget to do restart timer job

Comment: @Supermode restarting the timer job service fixed the problem, I guess every time when change is made we need to do the restart

Comment: perhaps you can put in the powershell script to restart timerjob on servers on the farm once deployed the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You follow the steps for SharePoint 2013 on premise site to deploy the custom timer job.

1. Change the feature of the Scope to "Site" in visual studio.
2. re deploy the solution through power shell or visual studio(if exists) on deployment server
3. activate the feature using power shell. If deployment using visual studio, feature activates automatically.
4. re start the timer service.